# Return field names using Arcade function in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I'm trying to write an expression for a pop up in ArcGIS Online that will display the name of the fields if there is a specific value under those fields for each feature. I adapted the following script that I found online.

```js
var i = 0
var features = [];

function addvalue(feat) {
    if (!IsEmpty(feat)) {
        features[i++] = feat;
    }
}

addvalue($feature.schoolCommGardenQuarter);
addvalue($feature.smarterLunchQUARTER);
addvalue($feature.schoolWellnessQuarter);
addvalue($feature.keysNAPSACCquarter);
addvalue($feature.healthConcessionsQuarter);
addvalue($feature.foodPantryBackpackQuarter);
addvalue($feature.farmMarketorPopUpQuarter);
addvalue($feature.rydQUARTER);
addvalue($feature.directEd);
addvalue($feature.onetimeRYDEventQuarter);

return Concatenate(features, ";")
```

This runs without issue but it returns the values as a concatenated list (such as `[YES;NO;YES;YES]`). I want to edit the above script so that it returns a text string of the field names that have `YES` as a value.

I have since edited my script so that the if statement evaluates for the 'yes' value. I still am having trouble figuring out how to access and return the field names rather than the 'yes' values.

```
var i = 0
var features = [];

function addvalue(feat) {
    if (feat == 'Yes') {
        features [i++] = feat;
    }
}

addvalue($feature.schoolCommGardenQuarter);
addvalue($feature.smarterLunchQUARTER);
addvalue($feature.schoolWellnessQuarter);
addvalue($feature.keysNAPSACCquarter);
addvalue($feature.healthConcessionsQuarter);
addvalue($feature.foodPantryBackpackQuarter);
addvalue($feature.farmMarketorPopUpQuarter);
addvalue($feature.rydQUARTER);
addvalue($feature.directEd);
addvalue($feature.onetimeRYDEventQuarter);

return Concatenate(features, ";")
```

Comment: Suggest you look at the help file. Your first issue is to test IF the value is yes. Look [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/) for code examples.

Comment: Thanks. Possible values in this dataset include 'yes', 'no', and blanks. I overlooked the inclusion of 'no' in this script.

Comment: @GIS Pragmatist is there anyway to edit your code to only return non-empty fields names + their attributes? This DOES NOT work but this is the idea: var returnstring = "List of All Values"+TextFormatting.NewLine for (var i in !IsEmpty($feature)) { returnstring = returnstring + i + ": " + $feature[i] + "; " + TextFormatting.NewLine } return returnstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could see doing it is to add an argument in your function for the field name. You have to add it manually to each addvalue call

```js
function addvalue(feat, field) {
    if (feat == 'Yes') {
        features[i++] = field;
    }
}

addvalue($feature.schoolCommGardenQuarter, "schoolCommGardenQuarter");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this, came across your question and have a solution.

Iterate $feature as below. Drop this into the [Arcade playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/) and see:

```
var returnstring = "AllValues"
for (var i in $feature) {
    returnstring = returnstring + ":" + i + ":" + $feature[i]
}
return returnstring
```