# Return non-empty field names and attributes using Arcade function in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I'm trying to write an expression for a pop up in ArcGIS Online that will display the non-empty field names and attributes. I adapted the following script that I found online [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282205/return-field-names-using-arcade-function-in-arcgis-online)

```
var returnstring = "List of All Values"+TextFormatting.NewLine
for (var i in $feature) {
    returnstring = returnstring + i + ": " + $feature[i] + "; " + TextFormatting.NewLine
}
return returnstring
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
var returnstring = "List of All Values"+TextFormatting.NewLine

for (var i in $feature) {
    if (!isEmpty($feature[i])){
        returnstring = returnstring + i + ": " + $feature[i] + TextFormatting.NewLine
    }
}
return returnstring
```